# How is it possible to stop sending any type of mail from Magento 2 based on the customer email value?

Tags: event-observer, customer, magento2.4, email, plugin

I am working on Magento 2.4 version and certain events that were available in older versions are not there now. I guess a plugin would be an ideal solution to this. Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: explain your issues into details.